# Intellisene is not working while using object literal for a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

**Background:**

I am using TypeScript with Vue and I have a component which handles the add and edit resource of an API. So, on form submit event I have used if else to determine the type of API which I need to call, so I have written:

```
this.$store.commit('app/setFullScreenHttpLoader', true);
if (!this.Data.Id) {
  delete this.Data.Id;
  this.Api.add(this.Data).subscribe(
    () => {
      this.$emit('save');
      this.$store.commit('app/setFullScreenHttpLoader', false);
      this.$showSuccessToaster(this.$t('add_success') as string);
    },
    () => {
      this.$store.commit('app/setFullScreenHttpLoader', false);
      this.$showErrorToaster(this.$t('add_error') as string);
    }
  );
} else {
  this.Api.update(this.Data).subscribe(
    () => {
      this.$emit('save');
      this.$store.commit('app/setFullScreenHttpLoader', false);
      this.$showSuccessToaster(this.$t('update_success') as string);
    },
    () => {
      this.$store.commit('app/setFullScreenHttpLoader', false);
      this.$showErrorToaster(this.$t('update_error') as string);
    }
  );
}
```

**Current Situation:**

Now you can see I have the same code both in the add and update method, so to avoid code duplication I have made another function and passed type to this function as `'add'` or `'edit'`:

```
public save(type: string) {
  this.Api[type](this.Data).subscribe( // <-- here I lose intellisense after [type]
    () => {
      this.$emit('save');
      this.$store.commit('app/setFullScreenHttpLoader', false);
      this.$showSuccessToaster(this.$t(`${type}_success`) as string);
    },
    () => {
      this.$store.commit('app/setFullScreenHttpLoader', false);
      this.$showSuccessToaster(this.$t(`${type}_error`) as string);
    }
  );
}
```

**What I need:**

This code works very fine but I lose the power of intellisense, any suggestions to get the intellisense here?

Comment: Please consider editing this code to constitute a [mcve] that someone can drop into an IDE and where the only problem present is the one you are experiencing.  My guess here is that you should annotate the `type` parameter not as `string` but as `"add" | "update"`, but I can't verify that as a solution without a reproducible example.  Good luck.

Comment: I can't believe that string values also be used as types.
Can you please answer `'add' | 'update'` thing? I wanna accept :)

Comment: Done.  I added a link to documentation about string literal types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain that this works without a reproducible example, but my guess would be that you want `type` to be annotated not as `string`, but as `"add" | "update"`, a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) that will give the compiler the information to know that `this.Api[type]` will either be the `add()` or the `update()` method, and hopefully bring you back some IntelliSense.  Like this:

```
public save(type: "add" | "update") {
  this.Api[type](this.Data).subscribe( 
    () => {
      this.$emit('save');
      this.$store.commit('app/setFullScreenHttpLoader', false);
      this.$showSuccessToaster(this.$t(`${type}_success`) as string);
    },
    () => {
      this.$store.commit('app/setFullScreenHttpLoader', false);
      this.$showSuccessToaster(this.$t(`${type}_error`) as string);
    }
  );
}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!